# Как посчитать кол-во слов с заглавной буквы

Tags: python-3.x

Нужно посчитать сколько слов начинается с заглавной буквы в строке

Answer (score 1):

например так:

```
words = 'Когда же Вы уроки будете делать САМИ?!!!'.split()

res = len([word for word in words if word[0].isupper()])

print(res)
```

или так:

```
res = sum(word[0].isupper() for word in words)
```